# Google Civic API: Error Code 400: "Failed to parse address"

Tags: android-studio, google-civic-information-api

I am recently trying to make an Android App, which uses Google Civic API to find the local officials based on the user input (a zip code). During testing, I found I randomly encounter Error 400: "Failed to parse address" when sending the query to API's endpoint.

I used the following format to do my query:
https://www.googleapis.com/civicinfo/v2/representatives?key=MY_API_KEY&address=zip-code

And for example, if the zip code input is 90210, it will show the following error when I clicked the query address:

{
"error": {
"code": 400,
"message": "Failed to parse address",
"errors": [
{
"message": "Failed to parse address",
"domain": "global",
"reason": "parseError"
}
]
}
}

Is anyone knows what happened and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Google has provided [an example](https://developers.google.com/civic-information/docs/using_api#representativeinfoquery-using-curl).

You can see in their example:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/civicinfo/v2/representatives?key=<YOUR_API_KEY>&address=1263%20Pacific%20Ave.%20Kansas%20City%20KS
```

It would still work even if the address has been shortened to:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/civicinfo/v2/representatives?key=<YOUR_API_KEY>&address=KS
```

If you provide the state along with the zip code, it will avoid the error.